# Cross platform VNC Client Library?

Tags: python, c++, cross-platform, vnc

Does anyone know of a good cross platform VNC client library (the viewer end)?

I'm not terribly picky about language, but I would prefer something with C++ or Python.  I would need it to work on Linux, Mac, and Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

libvncclient that comes with libvncserver is C and cross-platform: 
https://github.com/LibVNC/libvncserver

Comment: And covered by GPL thus totally useless.

Comment: Well, 'totally useless' is a bit of a political claim.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/python-vnc-viewer/ - should be cross-platform.

https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool - contains more enhancements on top of that.

Answer (score -1):

RealVNC has a Java Viewer (Java is cross platform), which is included in the free version, I am unsure about the license, though. Other VNC solutions might have something similar.

Edit: I found that thightvnc.com has a java viewer which seems to be GPL licensed. See:
http://www.tightvnc.com/download.html